# brew uninstall does not work cause of no space left on device

Tags: macos, mac, uninstall, disk-space, homebrew

I have low space left on my device and it was time to made some cleanup...

I removed a lot of things, trash, uninstall unused apps, caches, ... BUT

I installed "League of legends" for Mac a long time ago with `brew` and the game is huge, so I wanted to delete him like other app I do not use anymore...

```shell
$ brew uninstall league-of-legends
==> Uninstalling Cask league-of-legends
Warning: It seems there is already an App at '/usr/local/Caskroom/league-of-legends/latest/League of Legends.app'; overwriting.
==> Removing App '/usr/local/Caskroom/league-of-legends/latest/League of Legends.app'
==> Backing App 'League of Legends.app' up to '/usr/local/Caskroom/league-of-legends/latest/League of Legends.app'
cp: /usr/local/Caskroom/league-of-legends/latest/League of Legends.app/Contents/LoL/Game/DATA/FINAL/Champions/Lillia.wad.client: No space left on device
cp: /usr/local/Caskroom/league-of-legends/latest/League of Legends.app/Contents/LoL/Game/DATA/FINAL/Champions/Neeko.wad.client: No space left on device
cp: /usr/local/Caskroom/league-of-legends/latest/League of Legends.app/Contents/LoL/Game/DATA/FINAL/Champions/Kayn.fr_FR.wad.client: No space left on device
[...] and much more files...
```

It's like `brew` made a backup before uninstalling.
I tried to `force` the uninstall, but I got the same error :

```shell
$ brew uninstall league-of-legends --force
```

Do you guys know how to deal with this ?
thanks

Comment: Since that is a cask, why don’t you just try to manually remove it from the Applications folder? After you empty the trash, you should get a lot of space back, and then maybe the brew command will actually work also, just to clean up the brew meta-data.

Comment: nice tip ! actualy, I did what you suggest + I had to `rm -rf /usr/local/Caskroom/league-of-legends/latest/League of Legends.app` and then the `brew uninstall` command. Thanks a lot, if you want you can create a kick answer and I'll mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment on the original question to an answer, since this helped the Op.

I recommended that he delete the app manually from the Applications folder (in Finder or Terminal) and empty the Trash. He went further to also remove the downloaded cask under the homebrew directory and then was able to get “brew uninstall” to work.